# Install docker on RHEL 8.8. Service does not start because of error : "Failed to initialize nft: Protocol not supported"

Tags: docker, iptables, selinux, rhel8, nftables

We're trying to install docker on RHEL 8.8 :

- containerd.io-1.6.28-3.2.el8.x86_64.rpm
- docker-ce-25.0.5-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
- docker-ce-rootless-extras-25.0.5-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
- docker-ce-cli-25.0.5-1.el8.x86_64.rpm
- docker-compose-plugin-2.25.0-1.el8.x86_64.rpm

When starting service with "systemctl start docker.service", we get the error :

```
-- Unit docker.service has begun starting up.

Mar 21 17:36:03 lxdv0900pn dockerd[24896]: time="2024-03-21T17:36:03.898069768+01:00" level=info msg="Starting up"

Mar 21 17:36:03 lxdv0900pn dockerd[24896]: time="2024-03-21T17:36:03.950682664+01:00" level=info msg="[graphdriver] using prior storage driver: overlay2"

Mar 21 17:36:03 lxdv0900pn dockerd[24896]: time="2024-03-21T17:36:03.951001980+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."

Mar 21 17:36:03 lxdv0900pn dockerd[24896]: time="2024-03-21T17:36:03.961079983+01:00" level=info msg="unable to detect if iptables supports xlock: 'iptables --wait -L -n': `iptables/1.8.4 Failed to initialize nft: Protocol not supported`" error="exit status 1"

Mar 21 17:36:04 lxdv0900pn dockerd[24896]: time="2024-03-21T17:36:04.038947135+01:00" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="<nil>" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby

Mar 21 17:36:04 lxdv0900pn dockerd[24896]: failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: error obtaining controller instance: failed to register "bridge" driver: failed to create NAT chain DOCKER: iptables failed: iptables -t nat -N DOCKER: iptables/1.8.4 Failed to initialize nft: Protocol not supported

Mar 21 17:36:04 lxdv0900pn dockerd[24896]:  (exit status 1)

Mar 21 17:36:04 lxdv0900pn dockerd[24896]: time="2024-03-21T17:36:04.039602384+01:00" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="context canceled" module=libcontainerd namespace=plugins.moby

Mar 21 17:36:04 lxdv0900pn systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE

Mar 21 17:36:04 lxdv0900pn systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

We rebooted the machine, we tried to reinstall nftables and iptables, and changing versions.